# How to check enable hardware acceleration for canvas in Mac OS X webView

Tags: macos, canvas, webview, hardware-acceleration

I have developed an application for canvas which is working smooth on webView in some lower end macbooks but weirdly, on some high end macbooks, it is lagging with same webView. I suspect it is due to disabled hardware acceleration. How to check on mac webView if hardware acceleration for webView is enabled or not? If not enabled, how can we enable it?

Comment: why would hardware acceleration be turned off?  can it even be turned off?

Comment: In safari, the option to turn off hardware acceleration for canvas is disabled. But in most browsers, we can. Do you mean, in webView, itis always **turned on**? Any evidence for this?

Comment: I have no evidence either way; I just don't remember seeing the ability to toggle hardware acceleration in any Cocoa documentation.